# CREATE TABLE fails when i use an integer name for column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a dynamic form builder. Therefore PHP gets a set of names from a database and creates a new table with those names as column names. This works quite well until one or more names are integer (for ex. '12345'). Then the script fails.

How can I force PHP of MySQL to give numeric table names?

Here is a piece of the code (its still a draft):

```
$slaop = 'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id)';
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
$connector = new DbConnector();
$result = $connector->query( 'SELECT * FROM '.$form.' ORDER BY rang' );
while ($opslaan = $connector->fetchArray($result)){
  $slaop .=  ', ';
  $slaop .= $opslaan['tekstid'];
  $slaop .=  ' TEXT';
}
echo $slaop;
// OPSLAAN
$formnaam = $_GET['welkform'];
require_once 'dbconnectsave.php';
$connector = new DbConnectorSave();
$connector->query('CREATE TABLE '.$formnaam.'('.$slaop.')')
  or die(mysql_error());
```

`$opslaan['tekstid'];` is the part where the text of integer are called.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You shouldn't. It's not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a prefix that starts with a letter for your column names.

Answer (score 5):

Why not prefix all tables with the form name? Then integers don't matter...

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, this may not be a good idea.

**However, you can still do it if the column name is surrounded in backticks.**  Here's a couple of MySQL examples:

```
create table abc (id int, 123 int);  -- fails

create table abc (id int, `123` int); -- succeeds
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i force php of mysql to give numeric table names?

May be you can force your application not to use such field names?

And also change the whole design as well, without employing dynamically created tables, and use more usual approach of storing table structure in some table?

Comment: Sometimes it will be necessary to use only digits. And if i create a table in phpmyadmin it accepts every column name, even if its in digits.

Comment: Can you give me a use case where it'll be necessary to use digits as field names? I'm curious...

Comment: @MadHouse class 7b is a data for sure, not column name

Comment: Well maybe most of the time. But this is for a school with more than 5000 students. With this teachers can make a form whitout program skills. But if its not possible to use digits only of convert the php string to a string mysql can read, ill prefix something of just force the teachers tot use digits in combination with text.

Comment: @MadHouse So what? on the site I work for there are  500 000 registered users. And nearly 500 tables. And not a single one with numeric fields. 5000 students cannot be an excuse. It is your bad design that causing variable table names, not 5000 students. Still you fail to name a real reason for such a strange approach.